# Find the units digit of $572^{42}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

The idea of this exercise is that you use the modulus to get the right answer.
What I did was:

$$572\equiv 2\pmod {10} \\
572^2 \equiv 2^2  \equiv 4\pmod{10} \\
572^3 \equiv 2^3  \equiv 8\pmod{10} \\
572^4 \equiv 2^4  \equiv 6\pmod{10} \\
572^5 \equiv 2^5  \equiv 2\pmod{10} \\
572^6 \equiv 2^6  \equiv 4\pmod{10} \\
(...)$$

I can see that this goes 2,4,8,6 and then repeats. I remember that the gist of the exercise is to find the remainder based on this repetition. How do I do that? I know that $572^{42} \equiv 2^{42}\equiv ? \pmod {10}$. How do I simplify that 42 and answer this using that repetition?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compute $a^b\,\bmod c$ by hand?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand)

Comment: For the record, there was discussion here arguing that the proposed dupe is a very bad choice but it appears to have been deleted by a moderator.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is:

The reminder is repeating between:

$$R=\{2,4,8,6\}$$

Solve the following, since $|R|=4$

$$42\equiv x\pmod{4}$$

Have $x=2$, which means the reminder is the second term in $R$ that is $4$

Therefore $$572^{42}\equiv4\pmod{10}$$

Comment: For $2^{40}\equiv x\pmod{10}$:$$R=\{2,4,8,6\}$$
$$40\equiv x\pmod{4}$$
$$x=0$$
that means it's the last term in $R$, is that correct @pooja  $\overset{.~.}\smile$

Answer (score 2):

Notice the pattern in the indices, the indices that get mapped to each of $2,4,8$ or $6.$

Note that the indices $1,5,9,\cdots, 1+4n$ get mapped to $2.$ The indices $2,6,10,\cdots,2+4n$ to $4,$ the indices $3,7,11,\cdots 3+4n$ get mapped to $8,$ and finally all multiples of $4,$ of the form $4n$ get mapped to $6,$ where $n$ is a nonnegative integer.

Then you only need reduce $42$ modulo $4,$ which shows you that it is of the second form. Thus, you have that to the $42$nd power, your number is $4\pmod {10}.$

Answer (score 1):

Since you found $572 \equiv 2\pmod{10} $ you have to check only what is $$2^{42}  \equiv ?\pmod{10} $$

Since $2^5 \equiv 2$ we have $$2^{42} = 2^2\cdot (\color{red}{2^5})^8 \equiv 2^2\cdot \color{red}{2}^8 \equiv 2^{10} \equiv (\color{blue}{2^5})^2 \equiv \color{blue}{2}^2\equiv 4 \pmod {10}$$

Comment: I found a simpler way of solving it just now: since it repeats every 4 powers, do 42 (mod 4), which is 2. $2^2 \equiv 4\pmod {10}$

Comment: Ah, that is actually the same as this solution

Answer (score 1):

Consider $2^k$ modulo $10$.

You will notice that it enters a repeating pattern: $2,4,8,6,2,4,8,6,2,\dots$

Where $2^k\pmod {10} \equiv \begin{cases}2&\text{when}~k\equiv 1\pmod 4\\ 4&\text{when}~k\equiv 2\pmod 4\\8&\text{when}~k\equiv 3\pmod 4\\6&\text{when}~k\equiv 0\pmod 4\end{cases}$

Now, consider the exponent in this case. It is $42$.  Since the pattern of $2^k$ depends on $k\pmod 4$, we see that $42\equiv2 \pmod 4 $. Therefore, $2^{42}\equiv 4 \pmod {10}$ which implies that ${572}^{42}\equiv 4 \pmod {10}$.

Answer (score 1):

You want $2^{42} \mod 10$.  You found that $2^4\equiv6\mod 10$.  Now $6^n\equiv 6$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ (you could prove that by induction), so $2^{42}\equiv2^{40}2^2\equiv(2^4)^{10}2^2\equiv6^{10}\times4\equiv6\times4\equiv4\mod10$.

Answer (score 0):

Applying $\ xy\bmod xz\,  =\, x(y\bmod z)\ = $ [mod Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242) to factor out $\,x = 2\,$ below

$\ \ \ \ \begin{align}(2a)^{\large 2+4N}\!\bmod 10 &\,=\, 2(2\, \color{#c00}2^{\large\color{#c00} 4N} a^{\large 2} \color{#c00}a^{\large\color{#c00} 4N}\bmod 5)\\[.2em]
&\,=\, 2(2a^{\large 2}\bmod 5)\ \ {\rm by}\ \ 5\nmid a\,\Rightarrow\ \color{#c00}{a^{\large 4}\equiv 1}\!\!\!\pmod{5}\\[.3em]
&\,=\, 4\ \ \ {\rm if}\ a\equiv \pm1\!\!\!\pmod{\!5}\end{align}$